# error adding a slideshow module to satchmo

Tags: django, satchmo

i have found a django slideshow and have installed it following the guide bellow

> https://github.com/clarle/django-slides
>
> Download and place the 'slideshow' folder somewhere on your PYTHONPATH.
> (i placed it in site packages)
>
> Add slideshow to your INSTALLED_APPS under settings.py.
> (I added it to satchmo store settings.py and also main satchmo settings.py to be sure)
>
> To use a slideshow in another Django application, you can refer to the slideshow object as slideshow.Slideshow in your Django models.
> (this i was not sure how to do or if i needed to)
>
> If you're not extending base.html, make sure you have jQuery 1.4.2+ and Slides 1.1.7+ in your templates somewhere. Use {% load slideshow_tags %} in whatever template you wish to use a slideshow in.

the module shows up in the satchmo admin page but when i try to add or change a slideshow i get an error

> DatabaseError at /admin/slideshow/slideshow/add/no such table: slideshow_slide
> Request Method: GET
> Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/slideshow/slideshow/add/
> Django Version: 1.4.20
> Exception Type: DatabaseError
> Exception Value:
> no such table: slideshow_slide
> Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 344
> Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
> Python Version: 2.7.9
> Python Path:
> ['C:\Users\Administrator\MyStores\store',
> 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\satchmo-0.9.3-py2.7.egg',
> 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\python27.zip',
> 'C:\Python27\DLLs',
> 'C:\Python27\lib',
> 'C:\Python27\lib\plat-win',
> 'C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk',
> 'C:\Python27',
> 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages',
> 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32',
> 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib',
> 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin',
> '..\..\apps',
> '']

i think its telling me that there is no database setup for the slideshow but am not sure if that is the case or if it is something else altogether as i am a python beginner, i would be gratefull for any help with this.

thanks

kev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to install the slideshow module from https://github.com/clarle/django-slides in satchmo

the solution in the end was really easy, all i had to do was to place the slideshow folder in my PYTHONPATH (i put it in the site packages directory)

i added   'slideshow',

to the INSTALLED_APPS section of my settings.py file in my custom satchmo store directory/folder.

and finally i opened a terminal/cmd prompt and executed the following command

> python manage.py syncdb

and hey presto the modules were added, the database updated with the new tables and once i had run the server and logged into the admin page i am now able to setup my slideshow

i hope this helps anyone else who needs the slideshow in satchmo as the clue to updating the database came from another install guide for a different slideshow which i thought i would chance it and have a go.